# Fornite API return image

Tags: python, json, api

I am really new to python and am wanting to try print an image from json data

I so far have this:

```py
import fortnite_api
import requests

api = fortnite_api.FortniteAPI('KEY')
headers = {'x-api-key': 'KEY')
shop = requests.get('https://fortnite-api.com/shop/br', headers=headers)
newsbr= requests.get('https://fortnite-api.com/news/br', headers=headers)
AES=requests.get('https://fortnite-api.com/aes', headers=headers)
print (shop.json())
```

As you can see, I can print the data from the item shop in text, but now how do I output that information as an image? I hope you guys understand what I am trying to say.
Please help

Comment: What do you mean by "print as image"?

Comment: If you are trying to actually view the image, I recommend Pillow. Get the image byte data from the json object then open it. Something like 
`import io
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
im.save() //if you want to save
`

Comment: Output an image is what I am wanting to do

Comment: Someone told me that I can get an image from working with the json data, but how do I do that?

Comment: https://fortnite-api.com/documentation   This is the website for the api

Comment: Looked at what the output was and I see image urls. Those are what I needed., but how do i print them all?